# Wav2Lip creates a third set of lip/teeth

Tags: lipsync

I am looking to do a lipsync with wav2lip but it creates a third lip. I was wondering if someone could help.

Also, I want to lipsync in French, but the dataset used does not contain French videos but English ones. The problem, I think, comes from here, so, it would be greatly appreciated if anyone could point me toward a dataset with French videos that could solve my issue.

My video is initially more than a minute, I tried to cut it down in smaller parts but it didn't work.